# I want duplicate in an @ElementCollection

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hy, I use a `@Repositor CrudRepository<Player, String>`

to store some player Info.

Each Player have multiple cards, sometime the same more than once.

How can I allow-it in my player? I have error each time I try to insert one more than once

My code

```
public class Player {

    @Id
    String playerId;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Card.class)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    Collection<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

.

```
public enum Card {
    km25, km50, km75, km100, km200, crevaison, roueDeSecours, increvable, accident, garage, asDuVolant, feuRouge, feuVert, vehiculePrioritaire, panneDessence, stationService, citerne, limiteVitesse, finLimiteVitesse
;
```

Comment: How does CardType relate to Card?

Comment: @Matt Copy Past Error, sorry